# How tag wiki's peer review works? just like suggest edit of questions and answers?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I modified a tag's description, and I can see the new result of my version, but others can see the original version.

the page told me the message: 
Thanks for your edit!
This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.
[image]

I noticed that this peer review function is not similar as peer review of suggest edit.

How does it works? and the peer review of tag wiki will also appear in suggest edit queue?

Comment: What do you mean "not similar as peer review of suggest edit"?

Comment: @drachenstern Peer review of tag wiki is not real time, but the suggest edit's peer review almost real time. The question was sloved by YOU.

Comment: adding an at to the front of a name (@you) is the preferred way to indicate another user on the system ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> peer review of tag wiki will also appear in suggest edit queue?

Yeah, they appear in same queue.

[image]

And may be a little bit different with normal edit approval because tag wiki edits [approval needs 5k](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits)

Comment: peer review of tag wiki is not real time, but the suggest edit's peer review almost real time.

Comment: @Roy, they take time to get approved, becase people are not so sure about tag definitions. For me, I don't approve most of the tag edits because I am not good with tag definitions.